# How to update null values by the previous record in the same table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a table named "BBSEC2013_REPORTS" where some value in column "Q19_MARKETING" is NULL. What I want is to update those null values with the previous values of "Q1_UNIT_SERIAL_NO" in the main table.

SQL :

## FIND NULLS

```
SELECT R.BOOK_ID, R.QUESTIONNARIE_ID, R.Q1_UNIT_SERIAL_NO ,     R.Q19_MARKETING
FROM  BBSEC2013_REPORTS  R
WHERE ( R.Q19_MARKETING = 9 OR R.Q19_MARKETING  is null )
AND F_TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(R.Q6_IND_CODE_CLASS_CODE,1,2)) BETWEEN 10 AND 33
ORDER BY R.BOOK_ID, R.QUESTIONNARIE_ID, R.Q1_UNIT_SERIAL_NO
```

## SELECTING VALUE OF PREVIOUS UNIT

```
SELECT R.Q19_MARKETING FROM BBSEC2013_REPORTS R
WHERE R.BOOK_ID = * BOOK_ID OF SQL-1 
AND   R.Q1_UNIT_SERIAL_NO = * DECREMENT VALUE OF "Q1_UNIT_SERIAL_NO" OF SQL-1 
ORDER R.BY BOOK_ID, R.QUESTIONNARIE_ID,R.Q1_UNIT_SERIAL_NO
```

## UPDATING

```
UPDATE BBSEC2013_REPORTS 
SET Q19_MARKETING= Q19_MARKETING OF SQL-2
WHERE BOOK_ID = * BOOK_ID OF SQL-1
AND Q1_UNIT_SERIAL_NO = * Q1_UNIT_SERIAL_NO OF SQL-1
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by previous Q1_UNIT_SERIAL_NO? And what's the matter with your keyboard? Posting in uppercase is considered shouting.

Comment: Q1_UNIT_SERIAL_NO is a table column name... in the image.. look for 1st row. for Q1_UNIT_SERIAL_NO = 081 the Marketing result is null. I want to fill that null with previous Q1_UNIT_SERIAL_NO = 080 Marketing Value

Comment: Is the BOOK_ID and QUESTIONNAIRE_ID same for Q1_UNIT_SERIAL_NO  =080 and 081?

Comment: BOOK_ID + Q1_UNIT_SERIAL_NO  =  QUESTIONNAIRE_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to combine your supplied DML statements into one e.g.

```
UPDATE bbsec2013_reports r
SET    r.q19_marketing =
   (SELECT r1.q19_marketing
    FROM   bbsec2013_reports r1
    WHERE  r1.book_id = r.book_id
    AND    r1.q1_unit_serial_no = to_char(to_number(r.q1_unit_serial_no)-1, 'FM000'))
WHERE  (  r.q19_marketing = 9
       OR r.q19_marketing IS NULL)
AND    f_to_number(substr(r.q6_ind_code_class_code, 1, 2)) BETWEEN 10 AND 33
```

(**EDIT**) or if the decrement if not necessarily 1:

```
UPDATE bbsec2013_reports r
SET    r.q19_marketing =
   (SELECT max(r1.q19_marketing) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY r1.q1_unit_serial_no)
    FROM   bbsec2013_reports r1
    WHERE  r1.book_id = r.book_id
    AND    r1.q1_unit_serial_no < r.q1_unit_serial_no)
WHERE  (  r.q19_marketing = 9
       OR r.q19_marketing IS NULL)
AND    f_to_number(substr(r.q6_ind_code_class_code, 1, 2)) BETWEEN 10 AND 33
```

Now you could add additional `WHERE` clauses into the subquery if required e.g. `r1.q19_marketing <> 9 AND r1.q19_marketing IS NOT NULL` to find the previous record with a valid `q19_marketing` value.

Comment: Thanks man, I got the idea :) But what will be the idea if, without decrements it only by 1, I want to run a loop on  q1_unit_serial_number to find the previous valid data ??

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of OP).*

I got this solution:

```
DECLARE
V_MARKETING NUMBER;

BEGIN

FOR X IN (SELECT QUESTIONNARIE_ID FROM BBSEC2013_REPORTS 
        WHERE Q6_IND_CODE_CLASS_CODE < 3400 
        AND (Q19_MARKETING IS NULL OR Q19_MARKETING=9) 
        )

LOOP
    SELECT Q19_MARKETING
    INTO V_MARKETING
    FROM BBSEC2013_REPORTS 
    WHERE QUESTIONNARIE_ID=(SELECT MAX(QUESTIONNARIE_ID) 
                            FROM BBSEC2013_REPORTS 
                            WHERE QUESTIONNARIE_ID < X.QUESTIONNARIE_ID
                            AND Q6_IND_CODE_CLASS_CODE<3400
                            AND (Q19_MARKETING IS NOT NULL OR Q19_MARKETING!=9)
                            );

    IF V_MARKETING > 0 THEN

        UPDATE BBSEC2013_REPORTS 
        SET Q19_MARKETING = V_MARKETING
        WHERE QUESTIONNARIE_ID = X.QUESTIONNARIE_ID;

    END IF;

    COMMIT;

END LOOP; 

END;
```